# TextFormField cuts last character input

Tags: flutter

I'm having a weird issue with a `TextFormField`, it cuts off the last input. If I type something like `hello`, it's gonna cut off the `o` and save `hell`. if I give it a space like `hello` , it's gonna save `hello`. Has anyone been through the same issue and know how to fix it?

here is my code:

```
 String messageText;

 _ChatScreenState() {
 _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 _scrollController = ScrollController();
 messageText = "";
 }

  Widget messageTextField() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: deviceWidth * 0.55,
      child: TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      validator: (text) {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          return 'Digite sua mensagem';
      }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (text) {
        _formKey.currentState.save();
      },
      onSaved: (text) {
        setState(() {
          messageText = text;
        });
      },
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Digite uma mensagem',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withAlpha(100))),
      autocorrect: false,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think `save()` is intended to be used with `onChanged`.

If you place a button somewhere and perform `_formKey.currentState.save();` within `onPressed` of the button, you should see the entire text value being saved.